# Update Oracle Database based on date column in R

Tags: r

I have a table in oracle database with date column in it.

```
           DATETIME       PRE_PROCESSING
1 2015-07-07 09:07:45.816             -1
2 2015-07-06 09:08:07.958              2
              a                b 
1             0                0
2             2                2
```

Reading the file through R like

```
conn <- odbcConnect("db", uid = "Ins", pwd = "123")
mytable <- sqlQuery(conn, "select * from table1")
max_date <- sqlQuery(conn, "select max(DATETIME) from table1")
update.query <- paste("UPDATE mytable SET a = -1 
                    WHERE DATETIME = ", "'",max_date, "'",sep="")
```

I am trying to update `a` column value to `-1` where `datetime` is the value stored in `max_date`.

My problem here is, when i load the data to R from oracle , the datetime column in the format of 2015-07-07 09:07:45.816.

But in oracle its like 07-JUL-15 09.07.45.816000000 AM

so when i do the update with date time its not matching.

Can anyone help me how to resolve this problem

Here max_date = 2015-07-07 09:07:45.816

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. I can't figure what you're trying to do on which data.

Comment: What class is `DATETIME` column/variable in R? In principle, you can reformat the date/time to match the string in the database.

Comment: Above table in Oracle , i have to call inside R . In that table i have to take the updated timestamp record . For that record, i have to update the column a = -1  through update query and finally my table should changed with the value a=-1 for the latest record